# Noty: Do not execute callback when closed by timeout

Tags: javascript, noty

I am using [Noty](https://ned.im/noty/#/) to display messages to the user. When a notification is clicked, the user is redirected to a page that displays further details about the notification. For this I am using the `onClose()` callback.

I would also like to hide the notifications after a short period of time. I am utilizing the `timeout` property for this.

The problem is that the `onClose()` callback gets executed even if the notification gets closed by the timeout. But since there is no `onClick()` or a similar callback available I believe that using the current approach is the best I can do.

Is anybody aware of a way to solve this or some sort of workaround? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In [Noty v2](https://ned.im/noty/v2/) is looks like they have a new `onCloseClick` callback you can use. Seems like its only called when the user clicks the noty to close it. On timeout it will still close the noty without triggering that callback.

Here is an example:

```js
noty({
  text: 'Alert: I am an error!',
  timeout: 3000,
  progressBar: true,
  callback:{
   onCloseClick: function() {
     console.log("you closed with a click");
     // redirect user here
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/noty@2.4.1/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
```